# Multiples readonly databases(backup connections) on sails.js

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, sails.js

i have 2 databases with readonly status on amazon AWS RDS, as readonly databases cant be multi-az, i need to control them manually, my question is, its possible to sails control each connection to use by default my readonly1 database and when this one fail on connect, start using the readonly2 database?

Thanks.

Comment: Writing a custom adapter should solve your use case. http://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/extending-sails/adapters/custom-adapters (That said, writing custom adapter can be overwhelming or overkill)

Comment: @Sangharsh i'm not so good to build an adapter, i will search for other methods, but thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What @Sangharsh said but also, Sails is great when your use case is fairly simple, when it is not then it's better to make use of elaborate methods of interfacing with the database (`mysql@npm`) and structure this into adapters/services/helpers.

On a more simple scope if you only wanted to read records and have it fall back to the alternative database for data if the connection fails then you could have like MySQLService with a `read()` method that does what you said if this is the only thing that you need to do.

That being said, you should do some research into load balancing the servers in AWS as you can do this in there without Sails related code :-)

Comment: Yeah, sure, i agree with you, the project grew too fast... i have an aws consultor, i think i will ask him some solutions to this case... i have loadbalancers for the application servers but not to database servers...